# react router query param string loads the default page '/'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4, react-router-component

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56evy.png)

I have a scenario need to load the component with a query parameter. if load flowPage/1234 the component loads correctly.

But if i load flowPage/1234/investigation its load a default page
Note: 1234 is an queryparameter

Comment: it depends if you use `exact` param on route

Comment: I think the problem is in your route ordering. Put ```flowPage/1234/investigation``` above ```flowPage/1234```

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding, you are probably nesting the routes with `path,url by react-router-dom`. just simply remove the `exact` from route that serves all nested routes will does the trick.